# Logistic regression: can weights be used as a predictor variable?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, proportion

I counted the number of birds in a flock, which gave counts like these:

```
set.seed(1)
number.birds.in.flock <- sample(51:500, 10)
number.birds.in.flock
# [1] 170 218 307 456 140 450 470 343 329  78
```

I recorded the species that formed each flock:

```
species <- c(rep("species.x", 5), rep("species.y", 5))
```

I then counted the number in the flock that were feeding:

```
set.seed(1)
number.birds.feeding <- number.birds.in.flock - sample(1:50, 10)
```

And the number of birds in the flock that were vigilant:

```
number.birds.vigilant <- number.birds.in.flock - number.birds.feeding
```

I then went on to model the number of the flock that were feeding. First I converted `number.birds.feeding` to a proportion:

```
proportion.feeding <- number.birds.feeding/number.birds.in.flock
```

I used a binomial generalised linear model, with `number.birds.in.flock` as a weight:

```
glm(proportion.feeding ~ species, weights = number.birds.in.flock, family = "binomial")
```

Here's my question, can I also `number.birds.in.flock` as both a weight and a explanatory variable like this:

```
glm(proportion.feeding ~ species + number.birds.in.flock, weights = number.birds.in.flock, family = "binomial")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can. Your model would imply that the proportion feeding depends on the size of the flock; and furthermore, proportions from large flocks should be trusted more than proportions from smaller flocks (that's the impact of the weight parameter).

Another option would be to use a beta-binomial model. See the betareg package. It allows for clusters (flocks in this case) of different sizes.

My main concern is with the model you have chosen. If flock size affects the proportion feeding, then presumably the birds are affecting each other, so responses are no longer independent. But perhaps your model will fit approximately well.